# jQuery Sortable: storing values in an multipledimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list (jQuery UI) formatted as something like this:

```
<ul class="baseList">
    <li id="3">Item 1
        <ul class="childList">
            <li id="68">Child 1 of Item 1</li>
            <li id="69">Child 2 of Item 1</li>
            <li id="70">Child 3 of Item 1</li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li id="8">Item 2
        <ul class="childList">
            <li id="81">Child 1 of Item 2</li>
            <li id="83">Child 2 of Item 2</li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get an array variable that consists out of something like this:

`var entireList = [];`
`entireList = [[3,[68, 69, 70], 8, [81, 83]]]`

So I can post that variable to PHP to process it in the database.

I cant seem to figure out how I can solve this in javascript. What I have so far is the following:

```
var childList = $('.childList, .baseList').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        opacity: 0.6,
        update: function(event, ui){
            var childArray = $('.childList').sortable('toArray');
            var parentsArray = $('.baseList').sortable('toArray');
            for(p in parentsArray)
            {
                postChildData[parentsArray[p]] = childArray;
            }
            console.log(postChildData);
        }
    });
```

Now that works for halve, my result is: 
`[3: Array[3], 8: Array[3]]`
Comes down to th point that it only takes the children of the first `<li>` element.

Can someone here help me to get an array like the one i've written above (entireList)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution:
I needed to create a new Array, within there I needed to store the Parent ID and also the array with childs.

The way to do that is replace the for loop with the following:

```
for(p in parentsArray)
{
   postListData[p] = Array(parentsArray[p], $('#' + parentsArray[p] + ' > ul').sortable('toArray'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it may not be proper css, but give the second list a different class name, i gave it childList2 in this example. If you do not want to modify the ul you could bump the differentiation up a level to the parent li as well

```
    var childArray = [];
    var childArray2 = [];

    $.each(childList, function(children) {
       childArray.push(children);
    });
    $.each(childList2, function(children2) {
       childArray2.push(children2);
     });
```

If that doesnt work I should stop guessing without a way to test it on my own. You

Comment: I am on a school computer so I do not know how to test anything right now, but would changing your variables to var childArray[] and var parentsArray[] make a difference? because aren't they just technically strings right now?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `childArray` in your for loop use this:

```
$('#' + parentsArray[p] + ' > ul').sortable('toArray');
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I'm a step further. But the parents are not updated when I move those around. Can u help me even more further?